# How to install 3G mobile broadband?

Tags: 10.10, networking, modem-manager

I never install 3G mobile broadband inside ubuntu since I'm using lucid and till now, maverick

How to make it run? I've tried so many ways to make it happen but still get the same result.

its only blinking but my ubuntu does detect nothing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I already install usb-modeswitch, but nothing still happen, the modem isn't being detected at all

[image]

Comment: [This][1] may be useful to help.<br>[1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143989/3g-usb-modem-not-working-in-12-04