# 3G USB Modem Not Working in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 3g, usb-modem

When I connect my 3G USB Modem to my laptop with 12.04, nothing shows up in Network-Manager. **This modem is working in 11.10 and the modem is shown in Network-Manager but not in 12.04 !!**

Here are the outputs of `lsusb` and `usb-devices` on two machines , one with 11.10 and the other with 12.04 :

**Ubuntu-11.10 :**

```
$ lsusb
    Bus 002 Device 009: ID 1c9e:6061  

$ usb-devices
    T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=01 Dev#=  9 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
    D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
    P:  Vendor=1c9e ProdID=6061 Rev=00.00
    S:  Manufacturer=3G USB Modem        ￴￴
    S:  SerialNumber=000000000002
    C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
    I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
    I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
    I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
    I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

**Ubuntu-12.04 :**

```
$ lsusb
    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1c9e:6061 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY WL-72B 3.5G MODEM

$ usb-devices
    T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
    D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
    P:  Vendor=1c9e ProdID=6061 Rev=00.00
    S:  Manufacturer=Qualcomm, Incorporated
    S:  Product=USB MMC Storage
    S:  SerialNumber=000000000002
    C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=100mA
    I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=(none)
```

As the output of the above commands show, the device is detected as a modem in 11.10 but in 12.04 it is detected as a USB storage (the device is both a 3G Modem and a SD-card USB adapter).

Any help ?!

Comment: What's the module and how is it connected?

Comment: and what exactly is the problem? you'll need to provide a lot more information if you expect anybody to understand your problem.

Comment: Is the stick recognized if you try to create a new connection under `System -> Preferences -> Network Connections -> Mobile Boradband`?

Comment: I always put the mobile broadband into USB port and wait for anything happen. but nothing happens. I am newbie. I apologize if you are not really understand of my question

Comment: i also try sakis3G but nothing happen

Comment: Put the stick in and then look at the output of `dmesg` - please include the relevant lines in your question.

Comment: @ok comp: Okay, you're new, no problem with that...but did you try my advice?

Comment: @ok comp what is the make and model of your 3G device? What ISP/Telecom provider are you with?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After a lot of searching and reading in different forums I found a solution to my problem. Please note that while the other answers didn't solve my problem, they might be helpful to others facing problems with 3G USB Modems (specially the [sakis-3g](http://www.sakis3g.org/) script).

I found my solution in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1969322), which I will detail in the following:

When connecting my USB modem, it is detected as a USB storage. According to that thread, running `sudo modprobe option` could make the device be detected as a modem. If not, it is also suggested to execute the following commands:

```
sudo su
echo 1c9e 6061 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id
```

where `1c9e 6061` is the device ID obtained from the `lsusb` command. This worked for my device and it was detected in Network-Manager. Note that you must become root using `sudo su` and running the command with `sudo` won't work.

To automate things, the following steps are presented:

1. `sudo su`
2. `nano /usr/bin/usbModemScript` and put the following in the file:

   ```
      #!/bin/bash
      echo 1c9e 6061 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id
   ```

   Then save the file (Ctrl+O) and exit nano (Ctrl+X).
3. `chmod +x /usr/bin/usbModemScript`
4. `nano /etc/udev/rules.d/option.rules` and put the following in the file:

   ```
       ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6061", RUN+="/usr/bin/usbModemScript"
       ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6061", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe option"
   ```

   Then save the file (Ctrl+O) and exit nano (Ctrl+X).
5. `reboot`

**NOTE :** You should replace the values `1c9e` and `6061` with the appropriate device ID values of your own modem.

After reboot, your modem should be detected when connecting it to the computer. Of course, this might not be the case (as it wasn't for me)! My device wasn't detected correctly after the first time it was connected to the computer. Instead, I had to disconnect and then reconnect it, and this time it was correctly detected as a modem in the Network-Manger. Some people might also need to restart the network-manager service (as I did):

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

================================================================================

Another potential solution is to use `wvdial`.

1. Installation: `sudo apt-get install wvdial`
2. Connect your modem to the computer.
3. Run: `sudo wvdialconf /etc/wvdial.conf`. If it says 'no modem found' then you are out of luck!
4. If the modem is found, run: `sudo nano /etc/wvdial.conf` and input your ISP information where needed by filling the fields you know about. Run `man wvdial.conf` in a separate terminal for information about the options. Once you are ready, save the file (Ctrl+O) and exit nano (Ctrl+X).
5. Now try to connect: `sudo wvdial`

For more information on `wvdial`, read the man page (i.e. `man wvdial`).

Hope this helps `:)`

Comment: Hi, what is option1?

Answer (score 6):

I have Huawei E156 HSDPA (3G) USB Stick and I did the following, also it worked for my samsung 3g mobile via usb cable.

```
sudo apt-get install wvdial
```

after installing wvdial type following lines in  terminal to edit wvdial.conf

```
sudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
```

Paste into your editor, the following lines:

```
[Dialer name]
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Phone = *99#
ISDN = 0
Baud = 460800
Username = " "
Password = " "
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = at+cgdcont=1,"ip","your Access Point Name"
Stupid Mode = 1
```

Whenever you have to connect just type in your terminal

```
sudo wvdial name
```

Now you will be online with blazing speeds. I think this method is less time consuming and faster than other methods.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x6061
```

And wait for some time. It always works for me

Comment: What should happen after this command ? Should it show-up in Network-Manager ?

Comment: yep, I hope so.

Comment: `modprobe - program to add and remove modules from the Linux Kernel`

Comment: Unfortunately this command didn't solve the problem and still there is no Mobile Broadband connection in my Network-Manager. Thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: @SeyedMohammad Normally this command also did not work for when modem was attached. 1. Remove dongle. 2 Run this command **here product should be Target** 3. Insert modem.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to use usb_modeswitch:

http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/USB_ModeSwitch

to change the type from USB MMC Storage to 3G USB Modem?

Comment: I assumed that UsbModeSwitch is a pre-installed module on modern Linux dirtros! Anyway I found another way to switch the device type, which I will fully explain as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install usb-modeswitch ? Ubuntu 10.10 must have come along with it . Try to check with Synaptics whether usb-modeswitch is installed . Once installed , plug in your USB modem and wait . There will be an option at the connectivity icon where it writes create new mobile broadband . Then follow the steps from the window . Im using usb modem with Ubuntu 10.10 and it runs fine . =)

Comment: its already installed. but once I plug the modem in, still nothing happens. FYI, I'm having this problem since I'm using Lucid

Comment: what is the model of your USB modem ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what brand and model your modem is? Huawei, Option or Sony Ericsson?
Some Huawei models need some tweaking. At the danish site here: http://scripts.linux.dk/joomla/index.php/mobilt-bredb%C3%A5nd/mobiltbredbans.html
you can download and run a script that will make most Huawei models work. You can translate the page with google translate ;-)

Comment: I used Huawei once, for the usb-modeswitch, it srill cannot work, because nothing still happen, even my mobile broadband modem didn't being detected. just the lights of my broadband keep blinking

Comment: I also already download http://scripts.linux.dk/joomla/index.php/mobilt-bredb%C3%A5nd/mobiltbredbans.html the following link, but the result still the same

Comment: now I am using CSL U2-TF modem, made in China that I borrowed from my brother. an the results is still the same. my ubuntu doesnt detect it

Answer (score 0):

install usb-modeswitch and use wvdial or gnome-ppp to connect to internet. You will also be able to connect using network manager if your modem is detected. usb-modeswitch is the trick.

If your modem has custom drivers available then install them.

Answer (score 0):

For this USB MODEM, try sakis-3g.
You can download it: http://www.sakis3g.org/#downloading

Comment: No I haven't tried that script. I was hoping there would be a standard solution to the problem, specially since the device works fine with the previous version of Ubuntu (i.e. 11.10).

Answer (score 0):

Just, use alternative connection, full update ubuntu. Connect again using your 3g Dongel.

And it will work fine!

Comment: I always keep my Ubuntu installation up-to-date (every-day), but unfortunately that didn't make my modem show-up in Network-Manager.

Comment: But it worked for me, try to use Wv Dial

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea as net setter is working in ubuntu 10.04, 11.04 etc.
Connect & add a mob bb connection in network manager.  For help with Network Manager look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager)