# 3G USB modem is not working in 12.04

Tags: usb-modem

When I connect my 3G USB modem to my laptop with 12.04, nothing shows up in Network-Manager. I tried method explained in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143989/3g-usb-modem-not-working-in-12-04), but nothing worked out.

My USB modem is being detected as USB MMC storage, similar to situation in that post. Both option 1 (creating script) and connecting through `wvdial` has failed. Option 1 had worked once but, it was getting connected through GSM, not through GPRS. When I try to connect through `wvdial`, it says no modem detected or busy.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

is it mobile broadband modem ? as what i know you need to go to network connection - edit network and go to the mobile broadband and click add..  there you need to setup where are you from to get the list of provider from your country

here the screen shot

[image]

and adding more information if you like to have auto connect Ubuntu 12.04 USB GSM Mobile Broadband Connection .. i hope this link help you .. http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-auto-connect-ubuntu-1204-gsm-mobile-broadband-connection-on-boot-startup-service

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. I have created mobile network as suggested you already. Problem is that ubuntu 12.04 is not recognising the modem as 3G modem instead it is detecting it as only usb storage device (USB MMC Storage) problem is exactly same as in this thread, http://askubuntu.com/questions/143989/3g-usb-modem-not-working-in-12-04 but that solution is not working. .

Comment: Hello,my problem is partially solved. I am able to connect to mobile broadband provided I connect it with reboot. If I disconnect for any reason, I need to reboot to reconnect it. Strange. At least any suggestion on this....

Answer (score 0):

**eject** your device from **terminal** or **disks**.

1)you can find disks at search of unity.click to the cd rom of your modem and at left top you could find a triangle above a line at the center of three options. it will say "eject the medium in the drive". click at here.

2)In terminal, type **eject** & press enter

you could find your modem at nm after 12 sec

for your **second question** try refreshing/restarting the network manager from terminal using the command,

sudo service network-manager restart

press enter and type your password that is, you can stop restarting of your computer or replugin of your modem