# Configuring a usb modem in Ubuntu 12.04 - toshiba laptop

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem

Strange Problem in Ubuntu
I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit version in my Desktop and when I plugged in 2 different USB modems they were promptly recognized and was able to configure them using network manager. But the same cards refused to be recognized on a Toshiba Laptop.

Running lsusb for one of them(desktop)

```
    cpcadmin@cpcadmin-SD30V10:~$ lsusb
    Bus 005 Device 004: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552/E1800 (HSPA modem)
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Running lsusb after a few seconds

```
    cpcadmin@cpcadmin-SD30V10:~$ lsusb
    Bus 005 Device 005: ID 12d1:140b Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. EC1260 Wireless Data Modem HSD USB Card
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Its only after the same card is recognized as 140b by ubuntu was I able to use the network manager to configure the internet.

The same card when plugged into the laptop would just stop with the first step where it was recognized as a 1446 device.

Any idea as to what I need to do in the laptop?

Thanks in advance
Regards
Vivek

Comment: did you install huawei linux drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this link it will help you .And there is the same question ask here .

[askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143989/3g-usb-modem-not-working-in-12-04?answertab=active#tab-top) and it has nice answer.

[How to install Huawei E173 Usb Modem in Ubuntu 10.04/12.04](http://www.umunthu.net/howtos/how-install-huawei-e173-usb-modem-ubuntu-10041204-lts)

Comment: Hi Thusitha,Thanks for your feedback. My problem is that the Desktop running 12.04 recognizes by card as 140b while the laptop running the same version of 12.04 recognizes it as a 1406.