# MTS USB modem on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: usb-modem

I have newly installed ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop. But it can not mount the MTS mblaze usb modem. So I am unable to connect to net. When I am typing *lsusb* on the terminal it is showing the device. How to mount it?

Comment: See this thread

  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143989/3g-usb-modem-not-working-in-12-04

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the below **question** as well **its answer**.

[please click here to find your answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487004/how-to-add-d-link-dwm-156-to-usb-switch-mode-for-automatic-eject-of-driver-cd)