# Cannot detect 'Mobilelink ML27 Telkomsel Flash' modem in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: usb-modem

I am now using the USB modem 'Mobilelink HSUPA 7.2 Mbps Model ML27' to try to connect to internet in ubuntu 12.04. However, it cannot detect my USB modem and I cannot install it following Network Connections > Mobile Broadband > Add. Anyone has the experience using this USB modem?

(This is brought in Indonesia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of searching, I am able to detect the 'Mobilelink HSUPA 7.2 Mbps Model ML27' USB modem, it is in this thread ([3G USB Modem Not Working in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143989/3g-usb-modem-not-working-in-12-04)). The product key 20a6:f00e is found by `lsusb` and `usb-devices`.

1. `sudu do`
2. `nano /usr/bin/usbModemScript` and type

   `#!/bin/bash
   echo 20a6 f00e > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id`

   Then save and exit.
3. `chmod +x /usr/bin/usbModemScript`
4. `nano /etc/udev/rules.d/option.rules` and type

   `ATTRS{idVendor}=="20a6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="f00e", RUN+="/usr/bin/usbModemScript"
   ATTRS{idVendor}=="20a6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="f00e", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe option"`

   Then save and exit.
5. `sudo reboot`

After reboot, it can be detected by Network Manager. I add it in the Mobile Broadband, with the following setting:

Country: Indonesia

Provider: Telkomsel

Plan: Volume-based

Number: *99#

Username: *empty*

Password: *empty*

APN: internet

Network ID: *empty*

Type: Any

PIN: *empty*

And I select the option 'Connect Automatically'