# How to install Grameenphone modem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb-modem

I connect the modem with USB and it detects it as a CD-Rom then I Explore the CD-Rom and get 3 folders, one of them is Linux. Explore Linux folder and copy PCL_Bengal_GP.tar.gz and paste it in Home folder and extract there. Write the following commands and press Enter

```
cd PCL_Bengal_GP
sudo bash install.sh
```

but it shows error like

```
/bin/Grameenphone_Internet: line 12: ./Grameenphone Internet: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this??

Comment: possible duplicate of [3G USB Modem Not Working in 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143989/3g-usb-modem-not-working-in-12-04)

Comment: Grammen Phone er modem auto detect kore. Install kora lage na.

Answer (score 1):

Please type `chmod +x install.sh` and then     `./install.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same problem and went Grameenphone care center, but they were not able to fix it because they had enough knowledge about Linux. Then I fixed it using below codes:

1. Set up Wine stable version at first

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install wine1.6
   ```
2. Then set up Grameenphone modem

   ```
   cd PCL_Bengal_GP     # go to your unzip folder
   chmod +x install.sh
   sudo bash install.sh
   ```

It will take a few times to install modem driver and finally you will get your modem GUI and press connect button to access internet.

Comment: Because, grameen phone  modem is actually made for windows system, if I do not install wine at first, grameen phone modem can not execute it's gui and can't run.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough just untar your Grameenphone_Internet.tar and find your install.sh bash file. Now open your console on this directory where the ‛install.sh‛ file exists and runs below command

Make it executable using, `chmod +x install.sh`

Start it using, `./install.sh`

It will then start setting up the modem driver. Use `sudo` if any permission related issue arise